# Definition of a measurable function with respect to $\sigma$ - algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

A function $X:(\Omega , \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}) $ is called a measurable function(or random variable with probability $P$) if
$X^{-1} (B)=  \{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\ \}$ $\in \mathcal{F}$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$

Here, $\mathcal{B}$ is a Borel $\sigma$ -algebra and $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$ - algebra of $\Omega$

I am trying to understand this definition, and I am considering a example of $\Omega =$ {$1,2,3$} with $\sigma$ - algebra = {$\phi, \Omega,$ {$1$},{$2,3$}}.
If $\omega =1,$ then $X(1) \in B$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}$, so $X(1)= \mathbb{R}?$

Am I right? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, your assertion $X(1) = \mathbb R$ is wrong.

Comment: @GEdgar Why is that? We can assume that $B = \mathbb{R}$ since $\phi^{c} =\mathbb{R}$ with respect to real line.

Comment: $X(1)=\mathbb R$ doesn’t even make sense. We have $X(1)\in \mathbb R$, i.e. it’s a real, not a set of reals.

Comment: It is good to consider your example $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\mathcal{F}=\{\phi, \Omega, \{1\}, \{2,3\}\}$. However, you never defined your function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and so no conclusions can yet be reached. You need to define your function $X$ by specifying values for $X(1), X(2), X(3)$. Then you can determine whether or not your function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. For example, can you show the function $X(i)=i$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ is not measurable?

Comment: @Michael if $B = (-\infty,2.5) $, then $ X^{-1} (B) =\{1,2\}, $ which is not in $\mathcal{F}$, so it is not measurable. Am I right?

Comment: @JAEMTO : Yes, that is correct. You could also notice $\{3\}$ is a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but  $X^{-1}(\{3\})=\{3\} \notin \mathcal{F}$.  If you changed the sigma algebra to $\mathcal{F}=Pow(\Omega)$ (the set of all subsets of $\Omega$) then all functions $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are measurable.